# Cast and throw exception if failed

Tags: c#

I need to cast an object as another and throw an exception if it fails, to check the type of the object.

What kind of an exception should I be looking to catch? That is, if casting fails, what exception does it throw?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it on msdn. InvalidCastException.

Comment: When you have problems like this, you really should just open a simple console application, try it in a controlled environment, and see what happens. It would be faster than posting a question here, or even checking MSDN - maybe 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx)